# What is TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]?

Tags: sql-server

I worked on many tables and all had this thing:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [modified_on] [datetime] NULL,
    [modified_by] [varchar](200) NULL,
) 
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

What is `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]` in SQL Server/Transact-SQL?

Comment: you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891816/sql-server-composite-pk-issue-when-columns-having-different-data-type)..

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms174979.aspx)

> **TEXTIMAGE_ON { filegroup | "default" }**
>
> Indicates that the text, ntext, image, xml, varchar(max),
>   nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and CLR user-defined type columns
>   (including geometry and geography) are stored on the specified
>   filegroup.
>
> TEXTIMAGE_ON is not allowed if there are no large value columns in the
>   table. TEXTIMAGE_ON cannot be specified if `<partition_scheme>` is
>   specified. If "default" is specified, or if TEXTIMAGE_ON is not
>   specified at all, the large value columns are stored in the default
>   filegroup. The storage of any large value column data specified in
>   CREATE TABLE cannot be subsequently altered.
>
> NOTE: In this context, default is not a keyword. It is an identifier for the default filegroup and must be delimited, as in TEXTIMAGE_ON "default" or TEXTIMAGE_ON [default]. If "default" is specified, the QUOTED_IDENTIFIER option must be ON for the current session. This is the default setting.

Comment: @MitulSheth:- What is not clear to  you? The manual speaks it all, it is used to to indicate the types stored in filegroup

Comment: Can anyone give a simple explanation. MSDN seems a bit high for me!

Comment: @R.T. Does it mean that we should specify it whenever we use varchar(max)? What if we don't?

Comment: @MitulSheth:- That one is also specified in the manual. *TEXTIMAGE_ON is not allowed if there are no large value columns in the table* Is it is not specified then the large datatypes are stored in default filegroup

Comment: @MitulSheth:- If you are not at all specifying it then it means default and everything will be stored in the default filegroup

Comment: As usual, the Microsoft description is as clear as Mississippi River water in springtime.

Answer (score 268):

Given that the format is:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName(...) TEXTIMAGE_ON { filegroup | "default" }
```

`TEXTIMAGE` refers to all big/unlimited-size field types: text, ntext, image, xml, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and CLR user-defined type columns (including geometry and geography).

Then, you need to know what Files and FileGroups are. From the MSDN entry on [Database Files and Filegroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189563.aspx):

> ### File
>
> At a minimum, every SQL Server database has two operating system files: a data file and a log file. Data files contain data and objects such as tables, indexes, stored procedures, and views. Log files contain the information that is required to recover all transactions in the database. Data files can be grouped together in filegroups for allocation and administration purposes.
>
> ### Filegroups
>
> Every database has a primary filegroup. This filegroup contains the primary data file and any secondary files that are not put into other filegroups. User-defined filegroups can be created to group data files together for administrative, data allocation, and placement purposes.

So,

```
CREATE TABLE ... ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Would appear to be somewhat redundant, as it is saying that the mentioned large-text-value columns should be stored within the primary filegroup, which is actually the default action.

Assuming the existence of a custom filegroup called CUSTOM, you would probably write something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ... ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [CUSTOM]
```

You would create a custom filegroup to store large binary or text, and in this case the 'normal' fields info would sit in a data file in the primary filegroup, while the associated 'large' fields would be stored in a physically distinct data file (in the secondary custom filegroup).

You would do this so that you could separate the core relational datamodel (which would presumably be relatively small in terms of disk space) from the large fields (which will require proportionally more disk space) - in order to allow distinct archiving or replication strategies to be applied to each filegroup.

Comment: Thank you for providing this *much* more understandable answer than the accepted one!

Comment: @Mitul Sheth Never too late to choose a better correct answer :)

Answer (score 4):

If you dont have any large text columns i.e. text, ntext, image, xml, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and CLR then you can just use:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [modified_on] [datetime] NULL,
    [modified_by] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.

Comment: @ReversedEngineer That syntax error is caused by the unnecessary comma at the end of:

`[modified_by] [varchar](200) NULL`

Comment: @OrizG Sure. Just wanted to help the writer of the answer to fix their sample code. Totally weird thing is that is no longer gives the syntax error on my machine (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU12) (KB4536648) - 13.0.5698.0 (X64))

Comment: @ReversedEngineer Nothing weird in this, it just means Microsoft have finally improved its query parser to make it resilient to details like this. It's the same thing for JSON items in arrays, or enums items in C# or whatever.