# SQL Server: composite PK issue when columns having different data type

Tags: sql-server-2012

see my code it is not working but could not understand why?

i was trying to create composite pk having columns with different data type

when i tried this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ControllerActionItems](
    [ControllerName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ActionName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RoleID] [int] NULL,

    primary key ([ControllerName], [ActionName],[RoleID])
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**getting this error message**

> Msg 1709, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Cannot use TEXTIMAGE_ON when a
>   table has no text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max),
>   non-FILESTREAM varbinary(max), xml or large CLR type columns.

### solved updated code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ControllerActionItems](
    [ControllerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ActionName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,

    primary key ([ControllerName], [ActionName],[RoleID])
)
```

Comment: So remove `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you need one of the indicated columns to use TEXTIMAGE_ON, such as if you used `varchar(MAX)` instead of `varchar(50)`. However, according to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784410/what-is-textimage-on-primary#33562173) what you're doing seems redundant anyways, as the default behavior is to store large-text-value columns in PRIMARY.

Unless you actually have a large-format column in the table, you should simply remove `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]` from the SQL statement.